# Is it possible to handle 1B requests per day with WCF architecture?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

I have machine learning WCF service written in .NET. Not very compute intensive, but there are some minor computations. There are 2 big shared collection:

- ConcurrentDictinary with stats and results
- MemoryChache inside `lock`s with user session details.

It working very fast and gives several milliseconds response(on client side) time inside LAN with not very intensive workload. As work load will be higher - ConcurrentDictinary, lock`s, MemoryChache(with GC) and WCF infrastructure(with WebServer) will be the limiting factors.

Now I have a customer with HUGE traffic, so I am expecting up to billion (up to 200m per day user-session * 5 request from one user) requests per day. And requests are synchronous(page load time will dependens on them) so I must to minimise response time.

So:

Can I make WCF infrastructure scale horizontally? Can WCF requests be parallelized to several endpoints in equal proportions?

To parallelize memory usage by MemoryChache and general computations I think can use some custom kind of MapReduce. Is there any build in distributed computation approach for .NET that can help me? AFAIK - no.
Maybe it is easier to rewrite evething in SCALA and use Hadoop or, better, Spark.
But don't want to rewrite evething :( Ideas?

Comment: Are you really doing 1 billion per day? that is 11574 requests per second, every second over a 24 hour period. Honestly, I doubt your customer has that many requests.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  up to 200 m  of user sessions per dayr. one user can make up to 5 requests.

Comment: The only real way to tell if your architecture will scale is to load test it.

Comment: Have you read through [the MSDN page on WCF load balancing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128(v=vs.110).aspx)? Basically they say if you are using HttpBinding just treat it like any other HTTP load balancing situatuion.

Comment: Writing service to handle 1 billion requests per day with WCF sounds like not the best idea... However if you can throw load balancer and a bunch of servers, why not. If you do not need to share state between different load balanced instances - it only depends on how many servers you can afford, even if you use WCF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, look in to load balancing for horizontal scaling. You can do this through a hardware solution with a traffic manager ([F5 is popular provider - click this link for more info](https://f5.com/resources/white-papers/load-balancing-101-nuts-and-bolts)), through a software balancer ([e.g. Consul](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/haproxy-with-consul.html)) or through your code - [there is a good sample on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/711977/WCF-Router-LoadBalancer).

Strategies for load balancing include round robin, or a resource based decision on which service is least busy.

With 1B transactions, the network may become the bottleneck which will force you to a hardware solution. For a crude solution with little routing intelligence you could host your service on 100 or 1000 machines on separate endpoints and then have your customer proportion the traffic to the nodes.

I think the most telling piece of information is if there is any shared state - do instances need to be aware of each other. If so, then you have more than simple load balancing to think about!

Comment: yes, as i have mentioned in the question - I have 2 big shared state collection. This collections updates can be handled with mapreduce approach.

Comment: Map reduce will ruin your response times. You need to think about how you can possibly partition the data, use aggregates etc to try and split out the processing. Sharing state across a few hundred or thousand instances is not going to perform, for each node you add you will increase overhead. Try think of a partitioning approach.